# What does "tell you love your honey" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

[image: Tweet]

It says "You have no tomorrow promised. So, **tell you love your honey.**"
Shouldn't be "...tell your love to your honey"?

https://twitter.com/eikaiwa_tw/status/685382110304010240

Comment: Just yell "I love my honey" and dash towards a beehive :P

Comment: Even the first sentence sounds a bit off "You have no tomorrow promised" The message is probably saying: "*You don't / never know what may happen tomorrow, so tell your wife/girlfriend/sweetheart/honey/dearest you love her today.*"

Comment: Reading the Japanese sentence (I am a fluent Japanese speaker), the exact translation would be as follows: **You never know what could happen tomorrow (in the future). Therefore, let's convey this message (to everyone), "I love you."** There is no object in the second clause, which means you convey the message to everyone you know.

Comment: I suspect the English in this tweet is bad, and not by a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be "tell your honey you love her", but the author appears not to speak English natively.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the writer has confused the verb *tell* with *say*. In many languages these are broadly synonymous. In English, *tell* really requires an indirect object (the person you address), whereas *say* doesn't.

> So, say you love your honey.